# Change Mac terminal name before the @

Tags: macos, command-line

In my terminal app, it shows

> (base) jeffsungs@Sung-Macbook-Air ~ %

on every row. I know that Sung-Macbook-Air is the localhostname, and how to change it. But how about the writings before the @ (in this case is jeffsungs), what is its name and how to change it?

Comment: Which shell are you using? - the thing to search for is PROMPT and your shell - there are many tutorials and also questions here on how to set your prompt.

Comment: That `(base)` business is from Miniforge? See [How do I prevent Conda from Activating the Base Environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54429210/how-do-i-prevent-conda-from-activating-the-base-environment-by-default)

Answer (score 4):

This information is generally referred to as the prompt.

While there are differences between the various shells like `bash` and `zsh`, generally speaking [you can set prompt options by modifying the shell variable](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=PS1) `PS1`.

In `bash` start by looking at your current (default) prompt:

```
$ echo $PS1
```

You'll likely see `\u` which is the argument for the current user.

Set `PS1` to your liking and then export to your `.bash_profile` or `.zshrc` - I prefer a more compact one: `\h:\W \u\$`

Answer (score 0):

The name before the "@" is the user who is logged in. You can't change that unless you change to another user. The name after the "@" is the localhost determined by Apples's bonjour technology.

To change to the hostname, you could use the following command (as the super user)-

```
scutil --set HostName name-of-host
```

Comment: Isn't changing the part before `@` rather simple by redefining `PS1`?

Comment: To what? A static name? Both $USER and $LOGNAME are set by `login` and usually cannot be changed.

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted?  It's accurate.  Someone who only uses the face bubbles to log into their Mac may not realize that the OS assigned a username to them.

Comment: There are two ways one can read the "You can't change that unless you change to another user." part: a) you can't change your account name (so yes) or b) you can't change the text in the string (which you can by changing PS1). Given the level of knowledge shown in the question it may help to elaborate on this in an answer.